# Querying predicate in Prolog and java

Tags: java, prolog, swi-prolog, jpl

I want to make a query to use Prolog in java through JPL, I want to call a predicate like this in java:

```
predicate_test([X,Y,Z]):-
     a_predicate(X),
     another_predicate(Y).
```

I make the query in java to invoque "predicate_test" like this:

```
   Query q4=null;
    try{
        q4 = new Query("predicate_test(Percept).");
        System.out.println(q4.query());
    }
    catch(PrologException pl){

        System.out.println(pl.getMessage());
    }
```

I get this message from the catch block

```
PrologException: error(existence_error(predicate_test, /(schedule, 1)), context(:(system, /('$c_call_prolog', 0)), _37))
```

Whats wrong with my approach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you defining the predicate you are trying to use in your query?

Comment: @ScottHunter 'predicate_test' only has the definition shown above, is there anything else I have to add?

Comment: Sorry, I meant how is predicate_test getting asserted into Prolog so that your query can use it?  If it isn't in there, it would explain why your query can't find it.

Comment: @ScottHunter thank you, that was the problem, I wasn't calling my prolog file properly